# Why does it press the key, instead of holding it down?

Tags: python, macros, pyautogui

I'm using the pyautogui library and i tried to make a macro. The macro would switch the window to Roblox, then it would hold the WASD keys in order for 4 seconds.

This is my code:

```
import pyautogui as macro
import time as t

try:
    Roblox = macro.getWindowsWithTitle("Roblox")[0]
    Roblox.maximize()
except IndexError:
    print("Error: Roblox window not found")
    exit()

def  runmakro():
    Roblox.activate()
    macro.keyDown('W')
    t.sleep(4)
    macro.keyUp('W')
    macro.keyDown('A')
    t.sleep(4)
    macro.keyUp('A')
    macro.keyDown('S')
    t.sleep(4)
    macro.keyUp('S')
    macro.keyDown('D')
    t.sleep(4)
    macro.keyUp('D')

runmakro()
```